# Ограничение ввода чисел float

Tags: python

У меня есть переменная, которую вводит пользователь:

```
obj = raw_input('Enter %s: ' % (s))
```

она вводится в формате float, как мне ограничить ввод чтобы допустимые значения были от -90 до +90 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На каком-нибудь языке это выглядело-бы так:

```
while ( 1 ){
  obj = raw_input( 'Enter %s: ' % (s) );
  if ( obj >= -90 and obj <= 90 ) break;
}
```

Comment: хех, на питоне аналогично)спасиб)